# Detect visibility, hide on click of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have put together some code to make this work, but my Jquery skills are limited, can anyone let me know where i'm going wrong? I assume my syntax is totally incorrect. Thanks in advance for your assistance :)

```
// jQuery selector to get an element
var query = $('#menu .sub-menu');

// check if element is Visible
var isVisible = query.is(':visible');

if (isVisible === true) {
  // element is Visible
  $("#menu").click(function(e) {
    query.hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    // element is Hidden
  }
```

Comment: You are missing closing bracket `})` after `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: i think your if condition should be inside the click event.. to get the current status on click of the menu

Comment: mind to attached part of the html also? and also, the script seem to not complete for $("#menu").click, any error?

Comment: @guradio was just about to type that! :) Also becaue you're only using the variable once, it's better to just use .is in the if statement, less chars used :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch all who gave pointers here, and to Morpheus for solving the syntax, much appreciated :)!

Comment: So the issue was just missing brackets?  Did you look in the console for script error messages?  What IDE are you using?  Did that give any warnings/errors?   If you're writing code in notepad, have a look at: http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your same code is working just wrapped in `.ready()` method and **added `})` after `e.stopPropagation();`**. That was the error in your code responsible for your problem You could check that error in the console of your browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // jQuery selector to get an element
  var query = $('#menu .sub-menu');

  // check if element is Visible
  var isVisible = query.is(':visible');

  if (isVisible === true) {
    // element is Visible
    $("#menu").click(function(e) {
      query.hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  } else {
    // element is Hidden
  }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // jQuery selector to get an element
  var query = $('#menu .sub-menu');

  // check if element is Visible
  var isVisible = query.is(':visible');

  if (isVisible === true) {
    // element is Visible
    $("#menu").click(function(e) {
      query.hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  } else {
    // element is Hidden
  }
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  Menu
  <div class="sub-menu">
    Sub Menu
  </div>
</div>
```